# Export Einstein Analytics Datasets

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, analytics-api

Is there a way to do an automatic export of records periodically from Analytics Datasets? I need to send the records to a Data Warehouse Server.

Comment: Which salesforce Product you are referring to when you say einstein analytics. Marketing Cloud, Salescloud, ...? Einstein is consistently existent in all different products.